# iOS C++ poll timeouts after the app returns from background

Tags: ios, linux

### Environment

- iOS8.4
- xcode 6.4
- OS-X @ Yosemite
- Cross-platform C++ 11 code

### Use-case

- Asynchronous network communication is implemented using '[poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll)'
- [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) is called while having 'timeout' set to 2 seconds
- While [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll)ing the iOS device goes to the backgound and after a while goes back to the foregound ( app is not terminated in between )

### Problem at hand

While the app is running, if no IO event has occurred, [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) will timeout after the period of time specified at 'timeout' ( as expected ).
**However**, when going back to the forground ( after being in the background for a while ), [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) returns immediately w/o waiting for the specified timeout period.
Digging deeper, it seems that if the app was in the background for eg. 20 seconds, [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) immediately return for a total accumulated timeouts sum of 20 seconds and then will keep on operating normally ( timing out as expected ).

**Might I be doing something wrong with my code? Is there any way to avoid this behavior?**

I have applied the following work-around although I would really like to have it solved in the right way as this workaround might end-up biting me in the back...

```
        #ifdef TARGET_OS_IPHONE
            // NOTE: The following code is used to cope with a suspected iOS bug, future iOS versions might have that fixed, once this 
            // is fixed the code will adversly affect performance by causing poll to really wait for a duration in the amount of time 
            // the app was in the background
            if ((tNow - tLast) > ((int64_t)iWaitPeriod * 2)) {
                // iOS use-case, we have been brougth back from the backgound
                poll((pollfd*)m_pIOCPHandles, 0, tNow - tLast);// Account for the hibernation duration
                LOGTRACE(Collections, "IOCompletionPort::DoModal(), accounting for %.1f seconds of hibernation.\n", (tNow - tLast) / 1000.0f);
            }
        #endif
```